# Using a for loop with nested if statement to sum a total #

Tags: c++

Attempting to use this for loop to take an input for how many times the loop should run. And every other time the loop runs it should subtract or add to the sum, the denominator will change by +2 every completed loop. Cannot for the life of me figure out why it does not work. The answer I get once the input is larger than 10 is negative when it should be oscillating over pi.

```
 #include <iostream>  
 using std::cout;
 using std::cin;
 using std::endl;

enter code here

int main()
{
int input = -100;
double sumTotal = 4, denominator = 3;

    while (input < 0)
    {
        cout << "Enter Max value of k in truncated series (non-negative): " << endl;
        cin >> input;
    }
    if (input == 0)
    {
        sum = 4.0 / 1.0;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < input+2; i++)
    {


        if (i%2==0)
        {
            sumTotal -= static_cast<double>(4.0) / denominator;

        }
        else 
        {
            sumTotal += static_cast<double>(4.0) / denominator;

        }


        denominator + static_cast<double>(2);

    }

     cout << sumTotal << endl;


return 0;
```

}

Comment: `4.0` **is** a double, why do you use a cast here?

Comment: Because I was not sure how exactly the division would work. I read other places that an integer divided by a double would cause problems so I wanted to make sure it was a double.

Comment: Integer can never have a decimal part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: the `static_cast`s you are doing are unnecessary. In C++, literals of the form `1.0` are considered `double`s by default. Even if you used the float suffix, i.e. `1.0f`, the compiler will still do the right thing.

Second, while I'm not familiar with the algorithm you are implementing, I would bet the issue is here: `denominator + static_cast<double>(2);`. This statement has no effect on the value of `denominator`.

You probably need to do this:

```
denominator = denominator + 2;
```

Or,

```
denominator += 2;
```

The intended effect is to modify the value of `denominator` for the next iteration of the loop, so you must assign the new value to `denominator`.

Also, there doesn't appear to any different between:

```
for (int i = 2; i < input + 2; ++i) {
    ...
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < input; ++i) {
    ...
}
```

So I would recommend start your index variable at 0 for readability's sake.

Comment: Thanks! I was worried that 0%2 or 1%2 would not equal 0. That was why I added the +2.

Comment: Is there a way for me to make this as answered?

Comment: Sure, to the left of my answer there should be a big 0 and below that a checkmark in a circle. Click the circle to mark my answer.